# MongoDB - $sum in multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have many collections. The view of these collections is the same as the JSON. What I want to do is to collect the collections according to their id and create a collection. How can I do it?

A.json

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82152c"),
    "value" : 515835.0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82153c"),
    "value" : 6621696.0
}
```

B.json

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82152c"),
    "value" : 2118.0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82153c"),
    "value" : 1190.0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("423232d2d506c1cab1c1232c"),
    "value" : 10.0
}
```

Collect in A collection, id: 1, collection B id: 1 if it matches.

A in the collection, id: 2, if you are not in any collection, you are only showing that value.

In the last collection I have collected, I want to make a collection of objects and id in pairs.

Result.json

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82152c"),
    "value" : 517953.0 // A.value + B.value
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82153c"),
    "value" : 6633596.0 // A.value + B.value
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("423232d2d506c1cab1c1232c"),
    "value" : 10.0 // B.value (A.value : null)
}
```

i want this for multiple collections.

Comment: *to collect the collections according to their id* makes no sense. Please elaborate what you are trying to achieve. Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors worth reading.

Comment: `I have many collections` .. how many?

Comment: @sidgate 10-15 collections. i will calculate sizevalue.

Comment: @AlexBlex  How far can I elaborate? For example, I have 10 collections. I want to match these collections with the id's that they have, and collect them in a single collection. //

Collect in A collection, id: 1, collection B id: 1 if it matches.
A in the collection, id: 2, if you are not in any collection, you are only showing that value.
In the last collection I have collected, I want to make a collection of objects and id in pairs.
//
I can not speak good english, I apologize for that.

Comment: It is advisable to edit the question rather than explain it in comments. It makes question more readable, and increase chances to get an answer. Try to convert image to json, it is barely readable. Cross-collection queries are limited to $lookup operator, which works for 1-m relations. If it is not enough, you will need to do it on application level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1-0/1 relation given in the example you can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) as following:

```
db.B.aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
        from: "A",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "a"
    }},
    {$unwind: {path: "$a", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$project: {
        value: {$add: ["$value", {$ifNull: ["$a.value", 0 ]}]}
    }}
]);
```

It does ignore any documents in A, which have no corresponding documents in B, i.e. result have the same number of documents as in collection B.

Comment: Ty for reply, great.